# Current Location in the Simulator

Tags: iphone

Im doing an app in which i have to find the current location of the user.can i get the current location of the user in the iOS 5 simulator by using CLLocationmanager?

Answer (score 7):

xcode - Edit Scheme - Run you.app - Option

check Allow Location Simulation, then select "Default Location"

```
Add GPX File to Project
```

the format [like this](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=3120)

Answer (score 7):

In Xcode, you can select the location to simulate using a small button above the console.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"MapView";
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void) loadPin {
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *appleStore1;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;
    workingCoordinate.latitude = [latitude doubleValue];
    workingCoordinate.longitude = [longitude doubleValue];
    appleStore1 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [appleStore1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Default Point"]];

    //[appleStore1 setSubtitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance %.2f Miles",miles]];
    [appleStore1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeEDU];
    [mapView addAnnotation:appleStore1];
    [(MKMapView*)self.mapView selectAnnotation:appleStore1 animated:NO];
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = [latitude doubleValue];
    region.center.longitude = [longitude doubleValue];
    region.span.latitudeDelta = .5;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = .5;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    latitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    longitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    if (latitude > 0) {
        [self loadPin];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind, i formatted your answer a bit. But after second look to your answer: are you sure this is related to OP's question?